# Trying to select CSS3 elements in a nested <li> style menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, css-selectors

I have an HTML structure like this:

```
        <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services Offered</a></li>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="/residential">Residential</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/commercial">Commercial</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/industrial">Industrial</a></li>
                    </ul>
                <li><a href="/areas">Areas We Service</a></li>
                <li><a id="quote" style="cursor: pointer">Request A Quote</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

and CSS styles like this:

```
#nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}

#nav ul li:hover > ul {
    top: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    background: black;
}
```

The CSS code isn’t allowing the HTML nested `<ul>` to become visible on hover. I can understand this being a problem if the `<ul>` is a parent of the preceding `<li>` but its not, is it? How can I get this working without JS/jQuery?

Thanks!

Comment: Would you mind creating a fiddle? I have a feeling it has something to do with the `position:absolute;` property:value;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an invalid tag in your markup. `ul` cannot contain another `ul` it should be with in `li`. Apart from this i just fixed css removed `top:100%` and it looks this way. Not sure hw you wanted it.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/954Gw/)

#### Css

```
#nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}

#nav ul li:hover > ul {
  
    position: absolute; /* Change this to position:relative and your menu will appear  beneath its parent.*/
    display: block;
    background: black;
}
```

#### MarkUp Fixed

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Services Offered</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="/residential">Residential</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/commercial">Commercial</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/industrial">Industrial</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/areas">Areas We Service</a>
        </li>
        <li><a id="quote" style="cursor: pointer">Request A Quote</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yup, that was it!  Thank you!

Comment: The invalid markup was the only problem.  I can handle styling it on my own.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you didn't give `position: relative;` to the parent. And the main issue is, **`<UL>` is not inside `<LI>`**. So `:hover` will not be triggered. You need to move the UL inside the LI for this.

Why not think of doing something like this. Why not try with this HTML/CSS structure?

#### HTML

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 3</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

#### CSS

```
* {font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma;}
ul.nav {border-bottom: 1px solid #999;}
ul.nav li a {display: block; text-decoration: none; color: #333; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #fff;}
ul.nav > li:hover {border: 1px solid #666; border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;}
ul.nav li a:hover {background: #ccc; border: 1px solid #999;}
ul.nav > li {display: inline-block; position: relative; border: 1px solid #fff;}
ul.nav > li ul {display: none; position: absolute; left: -1px; width: 150px; border: 1px solid #666; border-top-color: #fff; margin-top: 1px;}
ul.nav > li:hover ul {display: block;}
ul.nav > li ul li {display: block;} /* Vertical Menu */
ul.nav > li ul li {display: inline-block;} /* Horizontal Menu */
```

#### Fiddle:
 http://jsfiddle.net/vMuxA/ (Vertical Menu)
 http://jsfiddle.net/vMuxA/1/ (Horizontal Menu)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

<strike>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/huBRT/)</strike>(Didn't add a toggle menu header)

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/huBRT/2/)

```html
#nav ul li ul {
   display: none;
}

#nav ul li:nth-of-type(3):hover ul {
   display: block;
}

<div id="nav">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Services Offered</a></li>
       <li>Toggle Me
          <ul>
             <li><a href="/residential">Residential</a></li>
             <li><a href="/commercial">Commercial</a></li>
             <li><a href="/industrial">Industrial</a></li>
           </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/areas">Areas We Service</a></li>
        <li><a id="quote" style="cursor: pointer">Request A Quote</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

> Note: You are having an invalid markup, you cannot nest `ul` directly
>   as a child under another `ul` element, you need to nest another `ul`
>   under an `li` element.

Also note that am purposely using `nth-of-type` here to select the 3rd `li` because if you want to nest another list under another `li` and you don't want to toggle that, than `nth-of-type` will come in action, else you want to toggle each nested list than using the below piece of selector will work as well

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/huBRT/1/)

```html
#nav ul li:hover ul {
   display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `ul` element is not contained within the `li` element that is being hovered over. Try moving the `ul` element within the 'hovered' `li` element.

Here's a jsfiddle I created; only moving the `ul` element to be contained within the `li` and adding `position:relative;` to the parent `li` element: http://jsfiddle.net/BQHyq/1/

If you have any feel questions feel free to make an inquiry - I'd be happy to help.